# Default handler for android.intent.action.CALL

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm having an issue consuming android.intent.action.call within my app.

What I am doing is the following, I have a android on a stick, which can't make phone calls, however, with the help of various diallers, they emit one of these android.intent.action.CALL intents.

I'm then planning on becoming the default handler for this intent, consuming it, and passing a message via a websocket to my phone that will then make the call (this bit is already working).

Currently, when I install Skype, it prompts with Mobile Data / Skype, and with the mobile Data chosen I get the following:-

`12-11 22:22:42.070 405-728/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxx flg=0x3000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster} from pid 24499
12-11 22:22:42.172 647-647/com.android.phone V/OutgoingCallBroadcaster: onCreate: this = com.android.phone.OutgoingCallBroadcaster@41c553b8, icicle = null
12-11 22:22:42.172 647-647/com.android.phone V/OutgoingCallBroadcaster:  - getIntent() = Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxx flg=0x3000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster }
12-11 22:22:42.188 647-647/com.android.phone V/OutgoingCallBroadcaster:  - configuration = {1.0 ?mcc?mnc en_GB ldltr sw853dp w853dp h1206dp 240dpi xlrg port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.8 themeResource=system}
12-11 22:22:42.188 647-647/com.android.phone V/OutgoingCallBroadcaster: processIntent() = Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxx flg=0x3000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster }, thread: Thread[main,5,main]
12-11 22:22:42.188 647-647/com.android.phone I/OutgoingCallBroadcaster: This device is detected as non-voice-capable device.
12-11 22:22:42.188 647-647/com.android.phone V/OutgoingCallBroadcaster: handleNonVoiceCapable: handling Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxx flg=0x3000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster } on non-voice-capable device...
12-11 22:22:42.188 647-647/com.android.phone V/OutgoingCallBroadcaster: - relaunching as a DIAL intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.DIAL dat=tel:xxx }
12-11 22:22:42.195 405-720/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.DIAL dat=tel:xxx cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity} from pid 647
12-11 22:22:42.203 647-647/com.android.phone V/OutgoingCallBroadcaster: At the end of onCreate(). isFinishing(): true
12-11 22:22:42.461 405-421/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity: +255ms (total +305ms)`

My question is, how do I become the default handler for either the android.intent.action.CALL or DIAL intents? (Presuming it's in the manifest) - btw I'm running 4.4.2.

Thanks

Adam

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this:

```
        <intent-filter android:priority="0">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="tel"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

It needs to be within an activity, where as previously I was trying to attach it to a service.